# How do I write a React Hook that Concatenates asynchronous data from other React Hooks

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, react-hooks, airtable

I have created a 'useFetchContentByGenre' hook in typescript React for returning TV Shows. It takes a value for 'genre' and a value for 'numberOfRecords' and queries an Airtable database.

```
const apiReadOnlyKey = "*********"

export const useFetchContentByGenre = (numberOfRecords, genreName) => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([])

    const [status, setStatus] = useState("idle")

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!numberOfRecords || numberOfRecords === 0) return

        const genreNameEncoded = encodeURIComponent(genreName)

        const airTableUrl = `https://api.airtable.com/v0/*********?api_key=${apiReadOnlyKey}&filterByFormula=FIND(%22${genreNameEncoded}%22,{Categories})%3E0&maxRecords=${numberOfRecords}`

        const fetchData = async () => {
            setStatus("fetching")
            const response = await fetch(airTableUrl)
            const json = await response.json()
            const data = await json.records.map((records) => {
                return records.fields
            })
            setItems(data)
            setStatus("fetched")
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [numberOfRecords, genreName])
    return { items, status }
}

//example of hook usage in file that imports hook
// import { useFetchContentByGenre } from "https://f****************"
//const { items } = useFetchContentByGenre(12, "Comedy")
```

I now want some kind of way (I assume via another hook) to concatenate data from different requests of the 'useFetchContentByGenre' hook.
i.e I first want to call 'useFetchContentByGenre' with a genre of 'Comedy' and then I want to call 'useFetchContentByGenre' but this time with a genre of 'Drama'. I then want both sets of data to be concatenated. I am not sure of 2 things.

1. In a file that contains multiple hooks, can one hook in the file use one of the other hooks in the file (e.g. can I have a hook called 'useFetchContentByMultipleGenres' that uses 'useFetchContentByGenre' in the same file).
2. How do I deal with the asyncronous behaviour of waiting for both requests of  'useFetchContentByGenre' to be returned before returning data from 'useFetchContentByMultipleGenres' to whatever functional component imports the new hook?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` to wait for both of your calls to finish and concatenate that in another state. Something similar to this.

```
const { items: comedyItems } = useFetchContentByGenre(12, "Comedy")
const { items: dramaItems } = useFetchContentByGenre(12, "Drama")

useEffect(() => {
   // do concatenation here
}, [comedyItems, dramaItems])
```

I had to rename items so you don't have clashing. `useEffect` will get called multiple times, sou need to do some checks inside it.

Your second question, you cannot use any type of branching when using a hook. This means that you cannot use a hook inside a useEffect for instance, or have an if/else.

You have a few options here:

1. Don't use a hook for the call. Use simple `fetch`, or other library`that's inside a`useEffect`and update a`state`.
2. Use conditional rendering that:

- Creates a new components that uses a hook (`useFetchContentByMultipleGenres` in your case)
- Pass any needed information to the component via `props`.

The second approach involves some boiler plate code, but if you need to use a hook that's pretty much your only option.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is helpful. I'll try both options.